# Angular 8: Update table after delete subscription

Tags: angular

I'm triying to update a table that is filled with a ngFor for each row, when i do the subscribe to delete a row it won't update the table but after leaving the page and returning...

These are the functions in my component.ts

```
  constructor(
    private _servicio: MaterialesService,
    private _dates: DatePipe,
    private _comun: ComunService,
    private activedRouter: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }

  p : number = 1;

  ordenes_fecha: any = [];
  ordenes: any = [];
  estatus: any = "";
  authority: string = "user";
  toDelete: number = 0;

ngOnInit() {
  const params = this.activedRouter.snapshot.params;

  this._comun.getCurrent();

  if (this._comun.authority == 'admin') {
    this._servicio.getOrdenes().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.ordenes = res
        this.authority = 'admin'
        console.log(this.ordenes)
      }
    )
  } else { 
    if (params.user) {
      this._servicio.getByUser(params.user).subscribe(
        res => {
          this.ordenes = res
          console.log(res)
        },
        err => console.error(err),
      );
    }
  } 
}

refresh(){
  this._servicio.getOrdenes().subscribe(
    res => {
      this.ordenes = res;
    }
  )
}

deleteOrden(id){
 this._servicio.deleteOrden(id).subscribe(
   res => {
     console.log(res);
     this.refresh();
   },
   err => console.log(err)
 )
 }
```

It work if i call the function `refresh()` in a particular button, but don't when i call the delete function... can someone tell my what im doing wrong? or if exist another way to do that?. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume `this._servicio.getOrdenes()` just use `httpClient.get` under the hood. `httpClient.get` completes after the get request. Your refresh method is useless since the observable from `getOrdenes()` has already completed.

Comment: Yes  `this._servicio.getOrdenes() ` is just  `httpClient.get` and i undestand you, but how should i refresh the ngFor that fill my table after delete?